# how to delay default action?

Tags: jquery, ajax

in jquery, i need to delay the default behavior of anchors, so that in the meantime, ajax post request can complete itself.

preventDefault or returning false in .click event wont do, as I still need to navigate to those pages. window.location = href obviously fails because some anchors do not have href attribute instead uses javascript. I do not control these pages.

Answer (score 1):

You just use the 'success' callback within the [ajax function for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) itself

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     // do what you need to here

     return true;
   }
 });
```

Then it will wait until the Ajax has completed before moving on to the success callback

Comment: yes but im talking about for links that do not have href url location. it is not possible to redirect within the success callback.

Comment: you just check within the success callback whether there is a href defined or not, if there is **not** then you return false. If there is, return true.

Answer (score 0):

If some anchors don't have href, I guess you'll not be able to change their behaviour. For the rest, just use a timeout on the click event and get href in order to redirect after the timeout ends, using its callback funcion.

Comment: if the "other" anchors use javascript to redirect, and you don't have control on it, yes.